# Virtualbox Guest keyboard not inheriting Host keymap

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox, keyboard-shortcuts, keymap

I have a MAC OS/X host system running a Xubuntu as guest.

In my MAC, in the shortcuts/key mappings, I chose to reverse the Command/CTRL keys (cause I use a PC keyboard and I'm used to it)

The problem is, that now in my guest machine, CTRL+C does not work anymore (of course) you have to do CMD+C...

Is there a way to instruct VirtualBox or my VM specifically not to obey the Host OS key mappings?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a selective key mapping to achieve what you want:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> acting as <kbd>cmd</kbd> in MacOS X environment,
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> acting as <kbd>ctrl</kbd> in VirtualBox environment.

[Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) is the software which will help you to do whatever you want in this field.

Have a look at this very good answer which exactly deals with your case:
[VirtualBox Mac - Is it possible re-map a key for a VM](https://superuser.com/a/487485/233562)